# Async/Await Nuances

Tags: javascript, async-await

I am trying to understand some of the nuances of `async/await` in Javascript and was hoping I can get some help here.

Suppose I have the following functions:

```
async function sum(a, b) {
    return await adder(a, b);
}

function sum(a, b) {
    return adder(a, b);
}
```

It's my understanding that the return values of the above functions are the same, due to `async` returning a promise, or wrapping non-promises.

Suppose `adder` returns a `number`. The first function will first resolve the `await adder` which will be a `number`, but then the `async` will wrap it as a `Promise<number>`.

Similarly, for the second one, a regular `Promise<number>` will be returned.

Am I correct in saying this?

Comment: Please show us `adder`, there's some ambiguity in your question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It's my understanding that the return values of the above functions are the same...

Not quite, no, but you seem to know that:

> Suppose `adder` returns a `number`. The first function will first resolve the `await adder` which will be a `number`, but then the `async` will wrap it as a `Promise<number>`.
>
> Similarly, for the second one, a regular `Promise<number>` will be returned.

No, not if `adder` returns a `number`. The second one (the non-`async` `sum`) will return a `number`, not  a `Promise<number>`, because neither it nor `adder` is `async`.

**If** `adder` returns a native `Promise<number>`, then the return values of `async function sum` and `function sum` are the same, although there may be a *slight* difference in timing.

There's never any real reason to use `return await x` unless you have it wrapped in a `try`/`catch` and you want to handle any error from `x` locally in the function. Otherwise, just `return` is sufficient, even if what you're returning is a promise. Until the ES2019 spec, `return await somePromise` and `return somePromise` were handled *slightly* differently, the settlement of the first was delayed one async tick longer than the settlement of the second, but if it's a native promise, a change in the ES2019 spec makes them the same even at that level. (But if `somePromise` were a non-native thenable, the extra tick would remain.)

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the `inline comment` for details.

```js
async function sum(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}
const promise = sum(1, 2);

// Here calling sum will return promise.
// Whatever you return it will be wrraped in promise[for simplicity]
// Above code is similar to

function sum1(a, b) {
  return Promise.resolve(a + b);
}

// Assuming adder funtion is async function

function adder(a, b) {
  return new Promise((r) => {
    setTimeout(r, 1000, a + b);
  });
}

// So calling adder
async function sum2(a, b) {
  return await adder(a, b);
}

// Equivalent to

async function sum3(a, b) {
  const data = await adder(a, b);
  return Promise.resolve(data);
}

// sum3 will return promise
sum3(1, 2).then(console.log);

// which is equivalent to

async function sum4(a, b) {
  return adder(a, b);
}
// sum4 will return promise
sum3(1, 2).then(console.log);
```

Answer (score 0):

async functions always return promises.
so assuming `adder` is async function both of the functions return promises.
in function 1 it will wait for the promise returned from `adder` to be resolved, once resolved it will return the number value, but async function always wraps the return value in promise if it isn't the in first place. so it returns a promise.
in function 2 it is because it returns the return value of `adder` which is a promise;

think of the return clause in async function as resolving the promise it returns.